# wildfly 10 - javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype

Tags: java, spring, servlets, wildfly

I am using Spring 4.3 and Servlet 3.1.
Deployment fails with error 
 javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype.
I know that it is some wrong class is loading

The Spring jars and Servlet 3.1 jars are configured as a module and mentioned in module.xml.

javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer is present in only one jar  jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar that I have included in module.xml.

SpringServletContainerInitializer is needed for my application. 
Let me know if you need me to post more details.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you including the server library, i.e. a library that includes `javax.servlet.ServletContainerIntitializer` in your deployment?

Comment: I think I solved the issue. Earlier I was adding jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar in my custom module. I removed it and added an entry in module.xml to include dependency like below      <dependencies>/>
   <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" />
</dependencies>

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while using wildfly 8. I also want to use SpringServletContainerInitializer for my application. Can you please provide more details of what changes exactly you did and on which file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by goig through my dependencies to see if anything crashed with my application-servers libraries.

Make sure your `java-ee` and `java-ee-web` dependencies are set to "provided" scope in your maven/gradle configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and after researching, I identified somehow  `SpringServletContainerInitializer` was not loading because of Maven packaging issue. In my case, `spring-web-4.3.8.Release.jar` was not bundling correctly with application WAR.

This can be fixed by

1. resolving application bundling conflict
2. using server shared libraries
3. if using IDE for application bundling, one can avoid bundling using IDE or switch the IDE (like STS to Eclipse/RAD)

Answer (score 0):

Another potential source of extra copies of servlet-api and other similar Java EE APIs is Spring Boot's tomcat-embed-core-<version>.jar, which you may get from spring-boot-starter-web.